# Chat program server class does not send messages

Tags: java, chat, user-input

I have this server code from a client-server chat program, but I figured when I run it I can only send one word every time for example "sending hello to 1" is OK and it sends 'hello' to client 1, but if I want to write a sentence I get "Invalid Message". I've been trying to fix it for a while now, and I can't get the right way to do it so I can get the message and the number of the client the message should go to.

```
public class Serverr implements Runnable {//server implements threading by implementing runnable interface
Socket csocket;
static HashMap<Integer,Socket>hm=new HashMap <Integer,Socket>(); //here we store each client socket in hashmap
static int k=1;
Serverr(Socket csocket){
    this.csocket=csocket;//Server ser=new Server(sock); comes here and assigns it to csocket
}

public static void main(String args[])
throws Exception{
    ServerSocket ssock=new ServerSocket(5000);//Socket on port 5000(same as mentioned inclient class)
    System.out.println("Listening");//when connected on port 5000 we print listening
    while(true){
        Socket sock=ssock.accept();//accept client socket
        Serverr ser=new Serverr(sock);//pass socket to constructor of server class
        new Thread(ser).start();//start thread here
        hm.put(k,sock);//add the socket into hashmap
        System.out.println("Connected to client"+k);//print the number of connected client 
        k++;
    }


}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        //once the thread is started we initialize necessary input & output streams here
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csocket.getInputStream()));//used to read input from the socket
        String inputLine;
        String j="sending"; //follow a pattern for sending messages
        String l="to";
        String t="sendtoall";//used to sent message to all clients
        while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null)//if the message from connected client !=null
        {
            String a[]=inputLine.split(" ");//split the input line using space if a[0] is sendmsg and a[2] is to
            if(a[0].equals(j) && a[2].equals(l))//we started the server
            {
                int id=Integer.parseInt(a[3]);//we will get the number of client here
                if(hm.containsKey(id)){// we will check hashmap if it contains id
                    Socket ser1=hm.get(id);//here we will get that clients socket from hashmap

                    out=new PrintWriter(ser1.getOutputStream(),true);// we will write to that socket using output stream
                    out.println(a[1]);//we will get that specific message part 
                    out.flush();// a[1] is...
                }
                else
                {
                    out=new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    out.println("user offline");//we print it if hashmap doesnt contain the key value
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
            else if(a[0].equals(t))//if we want to sent message to all clients at once
            {
                for(int h=1;h<hm.size();h++)//loop through hashmap & get those socket value
                {
                    Socket ser1=hm.get(h);

                    out=new PrintWriter(ser1.getOutputStream(),true);//we will write to that socket here using outputstream
                    out.println(a[1]);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
            else{
                out=new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                out.println("Invalid Message");//if the message format doesnt match
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157). Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @JimGarrison - Liana has described exactly what's going wrong.  I don't know how the question could be any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are these two lines.

```
       if(a[0].equals(j) && a[2].equals(l))//we started the server
        {
            int id=Integer.parseInt(a[3]);//we will get the number of client here
```

You are checking the third and fourth words of the input for "to" and a client number.  But if you've got a whole sentence, then these won't be the third and fourth words of the input.  Instead, you probably want to check the second-to-last and last words respectively, like this.

```
       if(a[0].equals(j) && a[a.length - 2].equals(l))//we started the server
        {
            int id=Integer.parseInt(a[a.length - 1]);//we will get the number of client here
```

which will allow you to have input such as

```
 sending Hello my friend to 12345
```

and identify the fields correctly.

You will also have to change the line

```
out.println(a[1]);
```

so that it sends more than just a single word.  Perhaps you could use a loop to do this, such as this.

```
for (int word = 1; word < a.length - 2; word++ ) {
    out.print(a[word]);
}
out.println();
```